# Using javascript to target class

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script in the head Element:

```
<script>
function changeOpacity(className) {

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
var index = 0, length = elems.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    elems[index].style.transition = "opacity 0.3s linear 0s";
    elems[index].style.opacity = 0.8;
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.red_box {width:100px;height:100px;opacity:1;background:red}
</style>
```

and the following structure in the body Element:

```
<div onmouseover="changeOpacity('.red_box')">Click to fade red boxes</div>

<div class="red_box">Box 1</div>
<div class="red_box">Box 2</div>
<div class="red_box">Box 3</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve the following: when the user clicks on the 'Click to fade red boxes' message, the function should make each div with the class: 'red_box' to turn transparent.
I would love some pointers (not Jquery please), Thanks!

Comment: The opacity is set to `1` in the CSS, and then your JavaScript code *also* sets it to `1`. Did you mean to set it to `0`?

Comment: Oops! Thanks Pointy - sorry for confusion. Yes, the function should have the opacity at 0.8
I have edited my question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the dot in the class name when calling the function:

```
onmouseover="changeOpacity('red_box')"
```

`document.getElementsByClassName(className)` takes the class name as a string. If you want to use a CSS selector, you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.red_box')` instead.

As pointed out by @pointy in his comment, you also set the opacity to the same as the initial value. Probably want to change that to something between 0 and 0.9, depending on the level of transparency you want.

Comment: I've been getting mixed up with needing the . in the class name for querySelectorAll and not needing it for getElementByClassName! Thanks Christofer

Answer (score 1):

You had set the opacity to the same in the css and the function, and also you needed to remove the dot in `onmouseover="changeOpacity('red_box')"`

Change your js function and html to be something like the below and it will work nicely.

```js
function changeOpacity(className) {

  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  console.log(elems)
  var index = 0,
    length = elems.length;
  for (; index < length; index++) {
    elems[index].style.transition = "opacity 0.3s linear 0s";
    elems[index].style.opacity = 0.5;
  }
}
```

```css
.red_box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="changeOpacity('red_box')">Click to fade red boxes</div>

<div class="red_box">Box 1</div>
<div class="red_box">Box 2</div>
<div class="red_box">Box 3</div>
```

Comment: Am now using this code - thanks Paul - it was definitely that addition I'd made of the dot in the class that was causing the main problem (but my typo of having the function's opacity set to 1 didn't help!)

Comment: @user2840467 no problem, glad to help!